# onSubmit event on a button element will it work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The following is the code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function call() {
                alert("hai");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="login" method="post" action="">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="login" onSubmit="call()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to create an event `onSubmit` inside the input element type `button`.

This is for an assignment. I was told by my tutor that it is possible. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: did you tried your code? does it give any error?

Comment: i think you should discuss this with your tutor.

Comment: You ask your tutor to give a demo on this

Comment: I think I will ask him to do that. I have been breaking my head over this for the past few hours since he was so sure about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `onsubmit` should be applied to the form as it's the form that gets submitted - not the button.

From the [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html):

> The onsubmit event occurs when a form is submitted. **It only applies to the FORM element.**

Answer (score 6):

Actually "onsubmit" is an event of `form` element. If you want to catch form submit event (which can be done by clicking button, automatically or by pressing enter, you need to do:

```
<form ... onsubmit="func();">
```

otherwise you can catch only submit button click event like:

```
<input type="submit" ... onclick="func();">
```

Comment: This is clearly the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible.

You should hook into `onclick` event of submit. A Form can have onsubmit event but a button cannot have the onsubmit.

You should do like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="login" onclick="call();">
```