# onSubmit Function not working correctly in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this Dialog component, which I opened this component, [image] it will shows the Dialog like this, However, I want to send whatever information I entered to the console, so like when I run `console.log()` I will able to see whatever text in the console after clicking the submit button, but it seems it's not working:( I used useState() to store the input value in the input, my concept is passdown the input to submit, so after submit, will whatever input in the console.

Dialog Component

```
<Dialog>
  renderTitle={renderTitle}
  renderContent={renderContent}
  renderAction={renderAction}
</Dialog>

const [input, setInput] = useState('')

const renderContent = () => {
 return (
  <form>
   <input>
    type="text"
    onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}
    value={input}
    placeholder='Enter MapStore Name' 
   />
  </form>
)
}

const renderAction = () => {
  const handleSubmit = (input) => {
    console.log(input)
  }
     return (
      <div>
       <Button onSubmit={handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
      </div>
    )
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onSubmit event on a button element will it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410128/onsubmit-event-on-a-button-element-will-it-work)

Answer (score 3):

Remove `input` from the `handleSubmit` method, because console log will out put the parameter value not the state value.

```
 const handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log(input)
      }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but somehow I still don't see it shows up in the console:(

Comment: is the onSubmit the correct format?

Comment: from where did you import button component?

Comment: so like I changed onSubmit() to onClick(), the input value shows up in the console, I don't know why is that

Comment: if you are using a HTML button element, then there is no props called `onSubmit`. it should be `onClick`. I thought this component was written by you

Answer (score 1):

> **GlobalEventHandlers.onsubmit**
>
> Syntax
>
> target.onsubmit = functionRef;
>
> Value
>
> functionRef is a function name or a function expression. The function receives a `FocusEvent`
>   object as its sole argument.

By that statement, when you do

```
  const handleSubmit = (input) => {
    console.log(input)  // <- input is the FocusEvent object
  }
```

You are getting the FocusEvent object in the input parameter.

If you want to log the input value, just remove the argument from the function so it takes the value from the state

```
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(input) // <- input is the value from the state
  }
```

Also, you should put the `onSumbit` prop in the form and use an input type submit to call it, unless you are using some sort of library that allows you to set the `onSubmit` in the button.

```
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    // your form elements
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```