# Is it possible to give a submit input button the onsubmit attribute with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, onsubmit

Hello I've tried several things to give my submit button the onsubmit attribute.
But I can't figure out, how to set onsubmit.
Maybe you have an idea.

```
let btn = document.createElement('input');
            btn.value = "Delete";
            btn.name = "deleteButton";
            btn.type = "submit";
            btn.onsubmit="deleteCell();
```

```
let btn = document.createElement('input');
            btn.value = "Delete";
            btn.name = "deleteButton";
            btn.type = "button";
            btn.addEventListener('submit', deleteCell())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "submit" event is for a *form*, not an *input*. You can use the "click" event on the input through:

```js
const deleteCell = () => {
    console.log("hello World!")
};
let btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.value = "Delete";
btn.name = "deleteButton";
btn.type = "button";
btn.addEventListener('click', deleteCell);
```

Answer (score 0):

A button does not have a `onSubmit` or `submit` event.

`onSubmit` is a property of a `<form>` element.

With button, you should use `btn.onClick = deleteCell` or `addEventListener('click',deleteCell)`

Have a look here for more details on a similar question.

[onSubmit event on a button element will it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410128/onsubmit-event-on-a-button-element-will-it-work)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Usually a submit button is wrapped inside a `<form>` tag. The form might have a `onSubmit` attribute or an action and a method. A button can have the `onClick` attribute to run a specific function.